# How to use age() function in a WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql

I use age function in where but i don't know why it does not work

```
select t1.id,date_part('year',age(t1.tdate,t2.birthday)) as age,t1.tdate,t2.birthday 
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE date_part('year',age(t1.tdate,t2.birthday))  >= 10
```

this result is incorrect

```
+-----------+-----+------------+------------+
|    id     | age |   tdate    |  birthday  |
+-----------+-----+------------+------------+
| 000327702 |   4 | 2017-01-05 | 2012-11-12 |
| 000337682 |   5 | 2019-02-07 | 2013-09-19 |
| 000337682 |   5 | 2018-09-20 | 2013-09-19 |
| 000337682 |   5 | 2019-04-04 | 2013-09-19 |
| 000264410 |  10 | 2012-09-12 | 2001-10-07 |
| 000383791 |  10 | 2017-07-19 | 2007-01-06 |
| 000221098 |  11 | 2016-07-29 | 2004-09-12 |
| 000342658 |  11 | 2014-02-12 | 2002-06-20 |
| 000234369 |  11 | 2017-06-12 | 2005-09-06 |
| 000330417 |  12 | 2013-02-21 | 2000-06-15 |
+-----------+-----+------------+------------+
```

this is the expected result

```
+-----------+-----+------------+------------+
|    id     | age |   tdate    |  birthday  |
+-----------+-----+------------+------------+
| 000264410 |  10 | 2012-09-12 | 2001-10-07 |
| 000383791 |  10 | 2017-07-19 | 2007-01-06 |
| 000221098 |  11 | 2016-07-29 | 2004-09-12 |
| 000342658 |  11 | 2014-02-12 | 2002-06-20 |
| 000234369 |  11 | 2017-06-12 | 2005-09-06 |
| 000330417 |  12 | 2013-02-21 | 2000-06-15 |
+-----------+-----+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Can you please post the table (or code to reproduce the table? The name of cols etc.

Comment: This works for me (without the join): https://rextester.com/NCX18511. Can you please create a [complete script](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with `create table` and `insert into` statements that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Does it work if you use `where age(t1.tdate,t2.birthday) >= interval '10 year'`

Comment: That work good for me Thank you  @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

It work

```
age(t1.tdate,t2.birthday) >= interval '10 year'
```